# What appears in the wake of a moving event horizon? For 2 merging black holes for example

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

When two black holes merge, their event horizon looks a bit like a spinning blob (see picture below). The fact that the event horizon of a black hole can move kind of confuses me, because some locations which were previously inside the event horizon are now suddenly not inside the event horizon. So what should appear in these regions? Or in more GR terms: for regions in regular (Minkowski) spacetime what 'appears' in that region is determined by its past lightcone. For the regions that I am confused about it appears to me that the past lightcone point entirely towards the black hole. Is that correct and if so how can these regions exist?

[image]

Comment: Here is the LIGO video of a merger  https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/video/ligo20160211v3 .

Comment: I doubt the premise of your question, by definition. Can you provide some examples?

Comment: What makes you think the past lightcone points towards the black hole? (Disclaimer: not a physicist) For that to happen these regions would have to form superluminally fast, otherwise stuff from the outside can/will be there, right?

Comment: @kutschkem I'm not sure about that. When I think about it, it seems the only logical option.

Comment: @ProfRob which premise do you mean? The fact that the event horizon is a spinning blob has been provided kindly by anna v or can be seen in this video https://youtu.be/Tr1zDVbSjTM . The premise that the past lightcone points towards the black hole is just a hunch and I'm not sure if it is true.

Comment: I mean the premise that something that was behind an event horizon can become "uncovered" at a later time. By definition, an event horizon is a surface for which that cannot happen.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Note that what you are seeing in that video is not the even horizon, but rather the shadow of the black hole.

Comment: @TimRias wrote: *"Note that what you are seeing in that video is not the even horizon, but rather the shadow of the black hole"* - that's not true, the [description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr1zDVbSjTM) says it shows the event horizons, by which they mean the [surfaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oYmAksBj0o&t=749s) outgoing light cone null expansion. That is not a [raytracing](http://org.yukterez.net/relativistic.raytracer/falling.into.a.kerr.newman.black.hole.html) of the shadow, that's a projection to the coordinate grid.

Comment: @Yukterez, Ah yes, I misread and thought they were referring to the video Anna v linked, which does show the shadow.

Comment: @TimRias - that's true, the other one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remember that the notion of an "event horizon" is global statement about the causal structure of spacetime, rather than some local statement. As such talking about the movement of such an object is fraught with difficulty, and any statement about such movement is bound to depend on exactly how one chooses to "slice" spacetime into surfaces of equal "time".

By definition, the event horizon marks the boundary of events in spacetime that can appear in the causal past (past lightcone) of any outside observer. This means that if on any time slice a point lies outside the event horizon, all of the causal past of that point must lie outside of the event horizon.

Now for your intuition. You seem to be led astray by applying Minkowski space intuition to the highly dynamic and strongly curved spacetime around a black hole (merger).

Although I do not necessarily like this language, the simplest way to think about the region of space just "behind" the motion of a black hole is as if this piece of space is being "dragged" along with the black hole. Imagine a ray of light just behind the black hole on a trajectory where it just barely escapes the event horizon. In "reasonable" global coordinates it may appear on a next time slice that this light ray has moved along with the black hole, and now exists at spacial coordinates previously inside the event horizon.

Comment: Nice answer. When you mentioned space is "dragged" along it clicked for me.